# I am using some scroll animations but it is causing horizontal scroll out of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have set up some scroll animations on many elements of a site I'm building.

I'm using these CSS rules:

```
.hiddenLeft {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translateX(-090%);
    transition: all 1s;
}

.hiddenRight {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translateX(90%);
    transition: all 1s;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

The hiddenLeft and hiddenRight classes are in the elements by default, and then when they are intersected during vertical scroll the show classes are added.

It all works fine, except it has created horizontal scroll to the right out of the width of the site into blank space.

I would like to keep the animations as they are but without the horizontal scroll.

A picture of me scrolling out to the side into the blank space for reference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq1Wy.png)

I made a very basic replication here:

https://codepen.io/acodeaday/pen/NWMYWNL

I can see that the offending line is

transform: translateX(90%);

But that makes the animation very aesthetically pleasing. So I'm hoping there is a way to solve it while keeping that.

Comment: It is scrolling out of the screen because of transform: translateX(-090%);

Comment: Yep i think it is because of the right hand side one, so transform: translateX(90%); But that makes the scroll animation very nice, so is there a way to keep it and prevent the horizontal scroll?

Comment: Can you please provide a working code so that it is easy to figure out the problem?

Comment: The website is quite large so its difficult to know what is relevant and what is not. I will try to recreate a simple version of the problem and post that.

Comment: Got it but you can create a quick demo. Provide only the necessary code. You can check here how to create an example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I was able to recreate it super basic actually https://codepen.io/acodeaday/pen/NWMYWNL

Comment: Can't able to see anything. You have used the path of your local directories. It won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
max-width: 100%!important; height: auto; overflow: hidden!important;
```

this code whatever you put all of your animation inside. That can be a div. Hope this help~

Comment: I just tried adding this to the .hiddenLeft rule and the .hiddenRight rule, but no luck, or did you not mean those elements?

Comment: I mean...You can use these properties to a div which covers all of your animation. I would suggest you to create a div right after the body tag and warp the whole code inside that div and give these properties to that div. That will get rid of horizontal scroll